# default allocated heap size for a Linux process

Tags: c++, linux

What is the default `allocated` heap size during a process startup in Linux? It's not about [ulimit](https://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) but because of noticing this [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/505038/no-system-call-when-malloc-after-free).

I also did the following test via `g++ -O0 -Wall -std=c++11` and `strace`, no syscalls for the change of heap allocation on `new, delete` the tested object were revealed.

```
 #include <iostream>                                                                                                   
 using namespace std;                                                                                                  

 class C {                                                                                                             
   public:                                                                                                             
     int i;                                                                                                            
 };                                                                                                                    

 int main() {                                                                                                          
     cout << "possible heap allocation below:" << endl;                                                                                    
     auto c = new C;                                                                                                   
     auto i = c->i;   
     delete c;          
     cout << "Was anything revealed above?" << endl;    
     cout << "i = " << i << endl;                                                                                                                                                                                                 
 }
```

**@EDIT**

As suggested, below it reveals quite precisely some space pre-allocated due to `libc` runtime and the changes of the space due to `new, delete` the object seen via `ltrace`:

```
 #include "malloc.h"                                                                                                   
 #include <cstdio>                                                                                                     

 class C {                                                                                                             
   public:                                                                                                             
     int i;                                                                                                            
 };                                                                                                                    

 void prnt(struct mallinfo info) {                                                                                     
     printf("Non-mmapped space allocated (bytes)       : %d\n", info.arena);                                           
     printf("Number of free chunks                     : %d\n", info.ordblks);                                         
     printf("Number of free fastbin blocks             : %d\n", info.smblks);                                          
     printf("Number of mmapped regions                 : %d\n", info.hblks);                                           
     printf("Space allocated in mmapped regions (bytes): %d\n", info.hblkhd);                                          
     printf("Maximum total allocated space (bytes)     : %d\n", info.usmblks);                                         
     printf("Space in freed fastbin blocks (bytes)     : %d\n", info.fsmblks);                                         
     printf("Total allocated space (bytes)             : %d\n", info.uordblks);                                        
     printf("Total free space (bytes)                  : %d\n", info.fordblks);                                        
     printf("Top-most, releasable space (bytes)        : %d\n", info.keepcost);                                        
 }                                                                                                                     

 int main() {                                                                                                          
     struct mallinfo before_ctor = mallinfo();                                                                         
     auto c = new C;                                                                                                   
     struct mallinfo after_ctor = mallinfo();                                                                          
     auto i = c->i;                                                                                                    
     delete c;                                                                                                         
     struct mallinfo after_dtor = mallinfo();                                                                          
     printf("\n--- memory pre-allocated?  -------------------- \n\n");                                                 
     prnt(before_ctor);                                                                                                
     printf("\n--- memory changed after \"new\" object?  ----- \n\n");                                                 
     prnt(after_ctor);                                                                                                 
     printf("\n--- memory changed after \"delete\" object? --- \n\n");                                                 
     prnt(after_dtor);                                                                                                 
     printf("\ni = %d\n", i);                                                                                          
 }
```

Comment: You'll want to look at functions like mallinfo(), malloc_stats(), and malloc_info(). These give you the actual information about the heap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no default heap size. The heap is always dynamic and starts at zero. The system calls used are `mmap`, `brk` and `sbrk`.

Most dynamic linked programs use heap in the program loader. They also use it when setting up output buffers for `std::cout`, `FILE *stdout`, etc. This is what you see as the "initial heap."

If you built a program without using the C runtime support libraries you would not see any heap usage.